# How to put the value of a newly created button as a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, button

I was just wondering how I would go about assigning the value of the HTML button being created (id="red") to the JS variable userInput? The value of that variable is taken from an HTML input textbox.

Here is my JS/jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#createGroup").click(function addGroup() {
    let userInput = $("#groupName").val();
    let newGroup = $("<input id='red' type='button' value='userInput' class='createdGroupsButton'>");
    $("#createdGroups").prepend(newGroup);
  });`
```

Here is the necessary HTML code:

```
<body id="containerMain">
  <div id="sideMenu">
    <div id="createdGroups" class="groups">
        <div id="groupDiv">
          <input id="groupName" type="text">
          <button id="createGroup">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Also, I have tried without the ' ' around the `userInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)

```
let newGroup = $(`<input id='red' type='button' value='${userInput}' class='createdGroupsButton'>`);
```